# How to Return "yes" if the first letter or last letter of the string is a vowel [ aeiouAEIOU ]

Tags: java, return, substring

This code focuses on strings, decision making [ if statements ], and parameter passing.

So far I have a runner class and the return method to use for the vowel:

```
public class FirstLastVowel {
public static String isVowel(String letter) {

        String fl = letter.substring(0, 1);
        String LL = letter.substring(letter.length() - 1);
        String vowel = "AEIOUaeiou";
        vowel.indexOf(letter);  
        if(
}
```

### }

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class StringRunner_Cavazos {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new File("firstLastVowel.dat"));

        while(fileIn.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(FirstLastVowel.isVowel(fileIn.nextLine()));
        }
    }
}
```

In the FirstLastVowel.java I have to put the substrings into variables and compare them to the indexOf(vowel) which is AEIOUaeiou and I'm stumped on what to type.

Edit #1: So I have changed some of the code, I removed the for loop and added 'vowel.indexOf(letter)' now how do I check the word if it's empty and return 'no' compared to if I can pull the first letter and the last letter and return 'yes'?

Comment: Hint: Java (and almost every other programming language) has a data type `boolean` to represent true/false (yes/no) data. It is generally much better design to return a boolean type in such cases instead of a String that holds the yes/no value.

Comment: In the first code, the for loop is completely useless : it can juste be replaced by a if to test if letter is empty or not

Comment: Checking whether a string starts with a vowel can also be done with a regex : `return letter.matches("[aeiouAEIOU].*") ? "yes" : "no"`. Are you allowed to use regular expressions?

Answer (score 2):

First, you do not need a loop: checking the initial letter is a one-time deal, you do not need to check letters beyond the initial one to determine if the word starts with a vowel or not.

You are on the right path with `letter.indexOf(vowel)` expression. However, you are ignoring the return value, which is why your code is not behaving the way you want. It should also be the other way around, i.e. `vowel.indexOf(letter)`

You need to check the result of the call to see if it is negative or non-negative. If the first letter is a vowel, the result is going to be non-negative; otherwise, the result is going to be negative.

The code should proceed as follows:

- See if the word is empty, and return `"no"` if it is
- Take the first letter of the word, and check if its index in the list of vowels is non-negative.
- If the index is non-negative, return `"yes"`; otherwise, return `"no"`.